# "Not being good at swimming, he didn't like it." Could we omit the word "being" here?

Tags: participle-clauses

> Not being good at swimming, he didn't like it.

Could we omit the word "being" here?

> Not good at swimming, he didn't like it.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, you can. But you can also improve your writing and avoid participles. You can rewrite your sentence dozens of ways. Here is one: *He disliked swimming because he wasn't a good swimmer.*

Comment: @AlanCarmack Would you care to elaborate as to why the reduced form is permissive? I thought participle clauses must comprise a participle, whereas Shirley decided to drop that integral part.

Comment: @user2684291 You might think of it as: "Since he was *not good at swimming, he didn't like it.*" It is just omitting understood information.

Comment: @user2684291 If I had time to elaborate I would write an answer. ;)  Nevertheless:  **(Being) a good insulator, rubber is often used in cables.** See also http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/phrases.htm#absolute  and http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/3441084324 and  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121630/absolute-phrase-without-a-participle-or-something-else

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I believe this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -ing form of a verb to give a reason by reducing a dependent clause, for example:

As he's not good at swimming, he didn't like it = Being not good at swimming, he didn't like it.

As commented by AlanCarmack, you can omit the present participle being in the participle phrase 'Not being good at swimming".

Answer (score 1):

> Not (being) good at swimming, he didn't like it.

There is no problem omitting *being* in such phrases.

Other examples include

> [Being] afraid of water, he didn't like swimming.
>
> Not [being] good at swimming, he became a boxer.

See also 12 other example sentences (Numbers 12-23) in [a similar question and answer](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/3441084324) at Azar Grammar Exchange. The first post is the question, and the second post gives the answers to each numbered sentence.